# Is there a way in Netbeans to start multiple instances of a program easily?

Tags: java, testing, networking, netbeans

I am currently developing a Client/Server application and whenever I am testing it I have to go through the following steps:

1. start the app in server mode
2. click a few buttons to make it start listening for clients
3. start a new instance of the app in client mode
4. click a few buttons to connect to the server

Both are the same app, running on the same development machine.

Is there any way to speed up this process through automation? I can't find any way in NetBeans to start two instances with two command line parameters with a button. I also tried using a batch file but to no avail. It will run two instances, but one after the other.

Comment: Hello @LinusV ! Your question seems a bit too open ended to be examined and answered accurately by the community. Could you share snippets of code that you have tried running and isn't working out ?

Comment: I would use a simple class with one method that does these steps for you.  Then just pick "Run File..." from the menu or use Shift-F6.  In some cases you can add a build target in your Pom/Gradle/Ant file and just run that.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 2 and 4 can be eliminated if you enhance the program to use command-line arguments, so certain arguments would be equivalent to "click a few buttons".

Then create two run configurations, one specifying command-line arguments for running in server mode and listening for clients, the other for running in client mode and connecting to the server.

Now you just need to do steps 1 and 3, i.e. start each instance separately.

Comment: This worked well, but I still needed to swap configurations which was a pain.. I improved on it by adding a check to see whether the server was running and starting as server or client depending on whether it was. I couldn't find an elegant way of doing this, so I just write a local file when the server starts and delete it when the server stops. It's quick and dirty, but for debugging it works well enough. Thanks so much!